# D3 js skip symbol conditionally

Tags: node.js, d3.js

following code adds symbols on multi series line chart.
I want to skip symbols for specific series among all. Can we conditionally skip a single series from being added in multi series line chart?

```
lineChart.selectAll("g.dot")
  .data(d3Data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .style("fill", "red")
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .selectAll("svg:path")
  .data(function(d) { return d.data; })
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("transform",function(d){return "translate("+x(d.key)+","+y(d.value)+")";})
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(d.seriesSymbol).size(22));
```

If I set value in `d.seriesSymbol` as blank of any garbage value then d3 by default displays circle. I dont want even this circle to be displayed. I am writing `d3.js` code in `nodejs`.
Do we have "none" kind of keyword to skip symbol?

Comment: When passing the data to the subnode, you may filter the passed data and eliminate unwanted items. So the items will not appear in the DOM at all.

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. I used filter and eliminated items which had d.seriesSymbol value as "none".